Configuring SSL truststore and keystore in spring boot latest version
I want to use https method in my spring boot project. I know that I need to use SSL. I want to configure the SSL keystore and truststore programmatically in JAVA not by application.properties.
Earlier I was using spring 3.1.3 in which I was using SslStoreProvider to set the properties. But, now in spring 3.2.3 it is deprecated and from spring 3.3.3 onwards it is removed. On documentation, it is showing you can use sslbundle.
I want to use sslbundle to set keystore and truststore programmatically. Not by using application.properties.
Here is my old implementation of SslStoreProvider:
@Bean
    public JettyServletWebServerFactory jettyConfigBean() {

        JettyServletWebServerFactory jef = new JettyServletWebServerFactory();
        System.out.println("JettyServletWebServerFactory");

        System.out.println("Exec Prakrath code!");
        jef.setSslStoreProvider(new SslStoreProvider() {
            char[] password = "changeit".toCharArray();

            @Override
            public KeyStore getKeyStore() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("downloadCerts and copyCerts initial load");
                System.out.println("SslStoreProvider getKeyStore is called");
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("/Users/prakrath/personal/teluskojava/servletjetty/src/main/resources/keystore.jks"), password);
                return keyStore;
            }
            @Override
            public KeyStore getTrustStore() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("SslStoreProvider getTrustStore is called");
                KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("/Users/prakrath/personal/teluskojava/servletjetty/src/main/resources/keystore.jks"), password);
                return trustStore;
            }
        });
              
        return jef;
    }

This is working absolutely fine, but I need to migrate to sslbundle
Here is my imlementation of SSLBundles
@Bean
    public JettyServletWebServerFactory jettyConfigBean() {

        JettyServletWebServerFactory jef = new JettyServletWebServerFactory();
        System.out.println("JettyServletWebServerFactory");

        System.out.println("Exec Prakrath code!");
        jef.setSslStoreProvider(new SslStoreProvider() {
            char[] password = "changeit".toCharArray();

            @Override
            public KeyStore getKeyStore() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("downloadCerts and copyCerts initial load");
                System.out.println("SslStoreProvider getKeyStore is called");
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("/Users/prakrath/personal/teluskojava/servletjetty/src/main/resources/keystore.jks"), password);
                return keyStore;
            }
            @Override
            public KeyStore getTrustStore() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("SslStoreProvider getTrustStore is called");
                KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("/Users/prakrath/personal/teluskojava/servletjetty/src/main/resources/keystore.jks"), password);
                return trustStore;
            }
        });


        jef.setSslBundles(new SslBundles() {
            @Override
            public SslBundle getBundle(String name) throws NoSuchSslBundleException {
                char[] password = "changeit".toCharArray();
                System.out.println("Inside SSL BUNDLE prakrath code!");
                return SslBundle.of(SslStoreBundle.of(
                        getKeyStore(password),
                        new String(password),
                        getTrustStore(password)

                ));
            }

            private KeyStore getKeyStore(char[] password) {
                System.out.println("downloadCerts and copyCerts initial load");
                System.out.println("SslStoreProvider getKeyStore is called");
                try {
                    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("/Users/prakrath/personal/teluskojava/servletjetty/src/main/resources/keystore.jks"), password);
                    return keyStore;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            private KeyStore getTrustStore(char[] password) {
                System.out.println("SslStoreProvider getTrustStore is called");
                try {
                    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                    trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("/Users/prakrath/personal/teluskojava/servletjetty/src/main/resources/keystore.jks"), password);
                    return trustStore;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void addBundleUpdateHandler(String name, Consumer<SslBundle> updateHandler) throws NoSuchSslBundleException {

            }
        });
        return jef;
    }

But this is not working, I am unable to send https request. There is not code available on internet to use sslbundles or any other way to set keystore and truststore in JAVA code.

Hi, Did you find a solution to add truststore and keystore with ssl bundles?

You can easily configure your spring boot server ssl configuration programatically, see here for a similar answer: Configure Spring Boot's with custom SSLContext programmatically (for mTLS)
